# use authorization token on multiple api websites

Tags: c#, api, oauth, bearer-token

I have created a secured Web API 2 website. I have used oAuth2 to authenticate requests and it works. I get an authorization token (bearer) which I can use to call data from that website. Let's call this the authenticationWebsite

However...I need to create multiple API websites. Is it possible that I authenticate myself on the authenticationWebsite where I get a authorization token and then use that token to call data from my other api websites?

I have tried a simple example and created another website (mvc) which gets the authentication token from the authenticationWebsite but when I try to get data from the new website (from a controller which has the authorize attrubute, I get the unauthorize error.

I hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out. It is important that the authentication server and the resource server(s) have the same Machine key in the web config.